# How to deal with different file types in HTML

Tags: html, windows, macos

I've a simple code for downloading a simple gif image.

```
<a href="file://<path_to_gif>/screenshot.gif" download > <button >Download Source Code</button></a>
```

Above code works smoothly in chrome browser in windows. But same code isn't working in Mac. In case of Mac, I should change the code to

```
<a href="smb://<path_to_gif>/screenshot.gif" download > <button >Download Source Code</button></a>
```

How can I make sure that it can be downloaded regardless of file system being used?

Answer (score 1):

Add the file locally to your site, so you can then use the absolute path from you page.

e.g.

```
images/
index.html


index.html = "images/mygif.gif"
```